# Restricting child class from accessing parent class method

Tags: java, oop, interface, protected

Say I have an interface I and classes A and B.

```
interface I
{
  method();
}

class A implements I
{
  method()
  { //Implementation 1
  }
}

class B extends A
{
  method()
  { //Implementation 2
  }
}
```

I want to restrict B from accessing 'method'. A call to b.method() should always use a.method() instead of b.method implementation where a and b are instances of A and B respectively. Is there any workaround?

Wish interfaces supported another access modifier to handle such cases.

Comment: @stealthjong final methods in interface ?

Comment: If "a call to b.method() should always use a.method()", then why does `B` even override `A`'s implementation?

Comment: What about an Abstract Adapter? Then you would have I, Abstract Class IAdapter implemting I and A and B extending IAdapter. In IAdapter you implement your "forced" implementation of the Interface method and make it final ... just for a start.

Comment: @dcastro I think OP wants to force all implementors to use A's implementation of that Interface method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stealthjong alluded to in their comment, you can achieve this by making `A`'s implementation of `method()` `final`:

```
interface I {
    public void method();
}

class A implements I {
    public final void method() {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}

class B extends A { }
```

Because `A` applied the `final` modifier to the implementation of `method()`, `B` cannot then redefine it and will instead always call the version that it inherits from `A`.

If I were to write:

```
B instance = new B();
instance.method();
```

I would see the output `"Hello World!"`.

Comment: You don’t need public in the interface method

Answer (score 0):

You can implement B like this:

```
class B extends A
{
  method()
  {
    method(true);
  }

  method(boolean callSuper)
  {
    if (callSuper)
    {
      super.method();
    } else {
      method_impl();
  }

  method_impl()
  {
    //Implementation method of B class
  }
}
```